# Multi-level object to single level object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying to map a complex object array document to a single level array. For example..

```
[{
    name: 'birds',
    references: [{ name: 'owl', value: 20 },
                 { name: 'sparrow', value: 23 }],
    identified: { created: '2014-02-02' }
}, {
    name: 'animals',
    references: [{ name: 'cat', value: 20 },
                 { name: 'deer', value: 23 }],
    identified: { created: '2014-02-02' }
}]
```

The objective is to turn the array into some thing like this regardless of the complexity

```
[{name: 'birds', references-owl: 20, references-sparrow: 23, identified-created: '2014-02-02'},
 {name: 'animals', references-cat: 20, references-deer: 23, identified-created: '2014-02-02'}]
```

Basically, if loop through each item in array and then loop through each property.

If the property is an array, add property to parent object with key composed of the name property from the array and parent key value like 'references-owl' and value from the property. All other array objects can be ignored beyond first level.

If the property is an object, prefix the key with the parent property and add it to parent object. If a child array exists, repeat above.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: That's a good algorithm you have here. Can you post your attempt at an implementation?

Comment: How is this unclear? This user has 2 sets of data, and he's looking to transform the first one into the latter.

Comment: @Cerbrus, it is unclear what the questioner is expecting from us (have you seen a question here?). Unless they want us to implement that algorithm for them, which I see you have just done. I thought you knew better.

Comment: Meh, once in a while, if others get rep from it... But I get the "unclear" reason now, yea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is exactly what you need here:

```js
var data = [{
  name: 'birds',
  references: [{ name: 'owl', value: 20 },
               { name: 'sparrow', value: 23 }],
  identified: { created: '2014-02-02' }
}, {
  name: 'animals',
  references: [{ name: 'cat', value: 20 },
               { name: 'deer', value: 23 }],
  identified: { created: '2014-02-02' }
}];

var result = data.map(function(row){  // For each row in data.
  // Set the static data in the result row
  var reference = { name: row.name, 'identified-created': row.identified.created };
  
  // Iterate over `row.references`, and add the current reference to the result.
  row.references.reduce(function(previous, current){
    previous['reference-' + current.name] = current.value;
    return previous;
  }, reference);
  
  return reference;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you @Cerbrus. The above answer is very interesting.   Is it possible to reduce the object without the static data reference, if it were an object like {x:{y:{z:{name:'cat', value:'12'}}}, a:1} to {a:1, x-y-z-cat:12}. This is just out of curiosity as I'm trying to understand how to implement reduce.

Comment: Yes, that's possible, but then you'd need to build a recursive function that would check for deeper levels... That's a completely different problem to solve.